# Get real-time data from a http long lived web service

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a http long lived web service. If it has new data it will push to client using http GET. How can I receive real-time data from http long lived web service with HttpWebRequest c#?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get data using Get, you can use this (the response is synchronous when you use GetResponse):

```
 public string GetMessageViaGet(string endPoint)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(endPoint);

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseValue = string.Empty;

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

                // grab the response  
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                return responseValue;
            }
        }
        private HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string endPoint)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            return request;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data via post, do this

```
   public string GetMessageViaPost(string endPoint, string paramtersJson)
        {
            string responseValue;
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paramtersJson);

            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(endPoint, bytes.Length);

            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }
                // grab the response  
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            return responseValue;
        }

        private HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string endPoint, Int32 contentLength)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = contentLength;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";// "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            return request;
        }
```